# React-Jest error: node:internal/process/promises:288 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */); TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, jestjs

The exact error is as follows:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288 
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */); 
TypeError: (0, _MyApp.getDataInfo) is not a function
```

This error occurs when I do

```
npm test
```

npm version: 8.19.2
node version: v18.12.1

This error started to occur when I upgraded my existing code from node14 to node18.
npm test in package.json: react-scripts test --runInBand --detectOpenHandles

jest version: ^28.1.1
react-script: ^5.0.0

Tried adding async and await in multiple test cases but that didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

```
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
```

enable this two options

Comment: How enabling "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames" will help this issue?
It clearly says it's a type error "triggerUncaughtException".

Comment: I have got the same problem, and I need some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: Hey all, sorry for the late reply but the solution is to mock the occurrence of this function and the set an appropriate return value. It does take time to debug but post that the issue is resolved.